# sampleVariable As Boolean = My.settings.sampleSettings (boolean dataType) doesn't work

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, visual-studio-2015, boolean, my.settings

I have a 2 scenarios that involves using `My.Settings.sampleSettings` with a `dataType boolean` and a `sampleVariable` as `data type boolean`.

**Code:** Since both sampleVariable and sampleSettings are boolean I declare them like that

```
Dim sampleVariable As Boolean = My.Settings.sampleSettings
Console.WriteLine("Result: " & sampleVariable)
If sampleVariable = False Then
    Console.WriteLine("1")
    sampleVariable = True
Else
    Console.WriteLine("2")
    sampleVariable = False
End If
My.Settings.Save()
```

**Output:** The output seems to not satisfy the condition 1, it always satisfies the condition 2 which is false

```
Result: False
1
Result: False
1
Result: False
1
```

**Code:** In this code I didn't put the sampleSettings to a boolean variable and it is working fine.

```
Console.WriteLine("Result: " & My.Settings.sampleSettings)
If My.Settings.sampleSettings = False Then
    Console.WriteLine("1")
    My.Settings.sampleSettings = True
Else
    Console.WriteLine("2")
    My.Settings.sampleSettings = False
End If
My.Settings.Save()
```

**Output:** Whenever I click the button it triggers a different condition, this is my goal.

```
Result: False
1
Result: True
2
Result: False
1
```

Question: How do I properly contain the My.Settings.sampleSettings to a boolean variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first block of code, you are not changing the value of the setting. You are only changing the value of the variable.

```
sampleVariable = True
```

This only changes the value of `sampleVariable`. It *does not* change the value of `My.Settings.sampleSettings`.

In the second block of code, you *are* changing the value of `My.Settings.sampleSettings`, which is why the value is being saved.